# Rails sudden Action controller Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

I'm working on a Rails project and this error showed up and I don't know what exactly is the reason.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root to: 'static_page#login'
resources :static_page
resources :users
resources :locations
resources :timetracks
get 'account', to: 'static_page#account'
get 'map', to: 'static_page#map'    
get 'login', to: 'static_page#login'
get 'signup', to: 'static_page#signup'
end
```

Comment: Do you have a controller named `StaticPageController` that is defined in `app/controllers/static_page_controller.rb`. Or it might be a typo in the `routes.rb` and you actually wanted to define `resources :static_pages` (plural)?

Comment: Figures, I must've deleted the controller that's why this error is surging. I really apreciate it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which means there is no class defined such as StaticPageController in your code.

// add this into your controllers folder

#### class StaticPageController < ApplicationController

#### end